# Any software to keep track of my reading progress?

Tags: productivity

I'm looking for a software which can keep track of my reading progress, like [BookMarker for iPhone](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bookmarker/id334329053?mt=8) does. It should be able to keep my everyday reading progress for each book I'm reading, and it will be better if other functions like calculating total reading pace are supported.

So is there any similar software on Linux/Windows platform? Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I humbly suggest web application http://www.goodreads.com/ or desktop applications [calibri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibre_%28software%29) and [FBReader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBReader).

Comment: +1 for Goodreads. My wife is a bookworm and she uses the site constantly. They also have an iPhone (and probably Android) app, both which expose the functionality of keeping track of books you've read. Being a webapp, it's about as cross-platform as you get.